# Как переопределить месторасположение "local machine cache" для nuget на linux?

Tags: mono, linux

Что такое machine level cache описано тут:
https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Machine%20Level%20Cache%20Part%201

Ну, то есть, чтобы пакеты скачивались не в директорию
~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache
а в указанное место

метки: nuget

Comment: быстрые английские коллеги рекомендуют через опцию repositorypath в конфиге - https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings

Answer (score 1):

путь можно задать в конфигурационном файле. из [документации](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings):

```
<config>
 <add key="repositorypath" value="/путь/к/репозиторию" />
</config>
```